# Should already accepted answers even be able to be flagged as "not an answer"?

Tags: discussion, flags, accepted-answer, not-an-answer

The description of the "not an answer" flag states:

> This was **posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

If an answer was marked as *accepted*, that practically proves that the given answer *did* help the asker solve the problem.

So, should it even be possible to flag accepted answers as "not an answer"? If I'm wrong, please give me an example or a constructed scenario of a situation, where this *is* appropriate.

Comment: `please give some examples of situations where this is appropriate.` The real examples of where it might be appropriate are most likely going to be deleted already so will be very difficult to find unless you know of a specific case.

Comment: @psubsee2003 then give me some constructed scenario.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Here is a recent example that I saw in the review queue.  The answer is terrible but it was the OP who posted it and accepted it -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504214/js-bookmarklet-grab-all-images/13714307#13714307

Comment: Scenario- OP: I want to do XYZ.. Answer: Try to use jQuery. Answer accepted!!! Flag it.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I think the scenarios where you want to flag an accepted answer will be rare, but bluefeet's example is an excellent one.

Comment: @bluefeet, you should post that as an answer (and include snippet from that "answer" in your post since that "answer" would probably be deleted soon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make a good argument, but there isn't a compelling enough case to block the use of this flag altogether for accepted answers.

Flags don't do anything automatically, they're raised to the attention of a human exception handler. The only way that any action will be taken is if that human decides that your flag is valid.

Consider it this way: if we made it impossible to flag accepted answers as "not an answer", what would we do in those rare edge cases where the flag *might* need to be raised? Conversely, if we leave it like it is, the worst that can happen is that some invalid flags get raised and have to be dismissed. Not a big deal.